# Facebook Graph API - Get profile picture prior to authenticating

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Ok so i've tried the following:

```
FB.api("/me", {fields: "picture"}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

And i'm trying to work around `http://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME_OR_USERID/picture` since obviously i don't know the users ID prior to authenticating.
All i want is a "modern" feel within the website, so i'd like to present the user with his or her's profile picture on the "login" div presenting the facebook login button. Is this possible? I know that Facebook and their graph api prohibits most such features but i would hope that a public profile picture would be accessible through the graph API..

I've Googled around and all the solutions say "use the USERNAME in the URL and you're fine" but i'm not, so to clear out any doubts, is this possible?

Error message: `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook app without prompted authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520300/facebook-app-without-prompted-authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have questions for you:

- How do you want to display the picture of someone without knowing who he/she is?
- How can you guess which account the visitor will use to connect?

It looks like you want to know whose Facebook account was lastly connected on the browser of your visitor. Technically, you would want to read another site's cookies, which is [1) not allowed 2) impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919968/php-read-a-cookie-that-is-on-another-domain).

Several additional things you need to know:

- `http://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME_OR_USERID/picture` **is** a public way to retrieve someone's photo. You don't need a token for that. What else do you need?
- Using `FB.API("/me", ...)` from the JS SDK implies that `"me"` represents the **connected** user. It cannot just be used alone.

By the way, identical questions have already been answered and **accepted**:

- [Facebook app without prompted authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520300/facebook-app-without-prompted-authentication)
- [Get Facebook user's profile picture prior to authenticating app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528086/get-facebook-users-profile-picture-prior-to-authenticating-app)

Why would you hope the impossible?

Comment: I'm aware of the dark sides of asking this question, such as the fact that i want to "know" whose Facebook session is visiting my site. I was merely hoping for the off-chance that it's possible for me to create a sleak "login with facebook" photo before the user even clicked it but yea, answer is no then (at least i gave it a shot).

Answer (score 3):

You can get everyone's Facebook profile picture without authentication.

You just call http://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME_OR_USERID/picture?type=large. This URL redirects you to image URL.

Type may be normal,small or large.